# How do I select a single item from a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary and I need to pull the string in position 0 of the list in the dictionary whose key is 2.

I've tried

```
dict = {
    0: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    1: ['item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
    2: ['item6', 'item7', 'item8'],
    3: ['item9', 'item10', 'item11']
}
print(dict[2[str(0)]])
```

and this gives me the whole list

```
dict = {
    0: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    1: ['item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
    2: ['item6', 'item7', 'item8'],
    3: ['item9', 'item10', 'item11']
}
print(str(dict[2])])
```

The first code gives me an error. It was just a shot in the dark anyway, but the second code gives me the whole string when I only want 'item6'

Comment: `dict[2][0]`. If you plan on coding Python I suggest a tutorial or even a book to get you started, otherwise stuff will take a long time to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code a bit. Try -

```
print(dict[2][0])
```

Here, `dict[2]` will return the list where key is 2. Then you need to extract element from that list. Here I used 0 as the index of the item you are interested. Change this code according to your need. One thing to note here is that the index for the list will always be integer.

One thing to mention is you might want to put this code inside a try-catch block in case the key for the dict or index in the list is not present. Another advice is to avoid naming your dictionaries `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
dict[key here][list index here]
```

For instance for the key = 0, and to get 'item1' ,use:

```
dict[0][0]
```